# How to check SEO meta tags in dev mode?

Tags: reactjs, express, seo, react-helmet

I have reactjs application with express server. I want to have my application as SEO friendly. I am using react-helmet to add SEO meta tags. How can I check SEO meta tags in dev mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react client side rendering. You should be able to see them in chrome dev tool.
(If you don't know how to open dev tool in chrome browser then just right click anywhere in the page and click inspect elements and go to elements panel.)

Remember react client side rendering will execute only when your bundle is fully downloaded on users browser.

Google now executes javascript too when indexing pages. If all that matters to you is google search engine then you are good.

you can go to [google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) to debug how google sees your site if its deployed out there for public to access

But if you want to be sure that your web pages are understood by all search engines like bing,duckduckgo,baidu (which may or may not execute javascript) then you either need to do prerendering of all pages using some sort of tool like [react-static](https://github.com/react-static/react-static) / [prerender](https://prerender.io/) or start rendering your webpages on server side and serve the html directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch an [Ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok) session on your dev server port.

```sh
ngrok http 3000
```

Ngrok will give you an URL and you'll have to put this URL in https://metatags.io

Answer (score 0):

find all meta details below mentioned ways

1. using view source
2. in browser inspect element
3. https://checkseo.io